# SharePoint 2010 Integration with Microsoft Office 2010

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, ms-office

I have a Development Project in motion where the end user interacts with an MVC Application to input data into it, then it gets submitted to SQL Server. Straightforward as it is really.  Then the data is used to produce a PDF Report.

I want to use SharePoint to pull the data from SQL Server to create a .DOCX and integrate Microsoft office word 2010 to edit the document and publish as a .PDF

The MVC Application, Not a problem. ITs SharePoint Integration with Microsoft Word I'm not familiar with.  SharePoint itself yes.  Integration and Automation with Office Business Applications, no really.

Can anybody point me into the direction of good solid resources online into Office Integration?

Im using Sharepoint Server standard 2010 so One Word Automation is out...

Comment: Why are you thinking OBA?  Are you going to add C# code into Word so anything that you change in Word will be pushed back to SharePoint?  Are you pulling data from SQL and exposing that as a BDC in Sharepoint?  I don't see any need for any of these if none of the above scenario is needed.  If the purpose is to just generate pdf and have it in a doc library why not just generate the PDF as part of the MVC app?  If you want to create docx instead, use OpenXml to generate it, much faster and cheaper resource than automating Word (not recommended on the server anyhow).

Comment: Both and/or either are on the table at this stage.  The reason that the PDF cant be published is that it needs to be redacted and signed off prior to it being published, otherwise id just user the pdfcreator class in c#. Using a BDC is a preferred option for me as I've worked with them before, however the formatting of the final document and for familiarity for its users I want to have Word integration into this process. That'll be either having word directly integrated into the SharePoint App (Preferred option) or integrating Word on the workstation into the finalisation process.  Thanks

Comment: Okay, can we assume the following... The purpose is to have a word document generated w/ data captured from the MVC app that is inside SQL that can be further edited / redacted by certain user.  Afterward, there is an approval / sign off process and finally a PDF version will be generated and published to a document library.  Does the intermediary step need to reside in the same library? can it be hold in a more secured library where only certain people have access to it (ones that need to do the redaction / sign off)?

Comment: If there is no need to refresh the word doc w/ the data after it's created, I'd still go with creating the doc as part of the mvc workflow instead of having Sharepoint do it.  Have that doc uploaded into Sharepoint lib that is setup to run the redaction / sign off workflow and as part of the sign off event, have SharePoint event handler that will generate pdf from the signed off word doc and push that into a published doc lib where it is accessible more publicly.  At that point, youj don't really need word integration into Sharepoint..?

Comment: Comment 1.  More or less precise other than the redaction and the approval is done by the same person (Minor correction, but the process is principally correct)  At this point, there is no document.  Just the SQL Data and Sharepoint with Word embedded (or the functionality at least) for the document creation.  Then Sharepoint will have a function to create the PDF.  It is then it'll be directly saved to the repository.  So in short, the only document that is created is the PDF.   Im under an assumption that a .DOC has to be created in order to use Word integration with SharePoint.

Comment: Comment 2.  Word is only there to manipulate the data that is in the BDC in Sharepoint. so intrinsically, I want sharePoint to look like word and have Word like functionality (Hence Office integration), the layout of the document will be in the older paper format that my employer is currently using, then once the redaction and editing has been done, then the PDF is created using Sharepoint and stored directly in the repository.  The purpose of this is to demonstrate to my employer the power of OBA, MOSS and LOB systems since they've invested in 22k in these and haven't seen any ROI.

Comment: I don't recommend going the OBA route if not needed.  Creating word / any office extension is a maintenance and versioning trap, been there done that and regretted it.  If you do not need to go that way... don't.  The marketing is nice, but in reality, it's a nightmare.  I'd recommend going the way that I mentioned above.  That still proof that the LOB in form of the web app still has value, MOSS still has value for doing document management and workflow and office is office and its useful enough on its own.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @JimmyChandra.  I totally get you on this, Don't office extensions and frankly, I'd not like to do it again EVER...  Of so taking word out of the process, what about this. Another idea of mine would be to deploy a Silverlight application within the departments Sharepoint page and lock it down using ADDS.  Give a dynamic feel, demonstrates the effectiveness of SharePoint and, if they want to create a word document in the app they can, as well as publish the .PDF.  I get design and feature governance, and I still get to showcase SharePoint as Business Delivery Tool..

Comment: Nothing wrong with that :).